# How to process the webresponse based on its contentType

Tags: c#, web, httpresponse

I want to process the response based on the content type. Is there any better method than writing response.ContentType=="application/x-zipcompressed" . i mean I can have rar or zip. I am wondering if it is a right solution to check it gainst a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into the "Chain of Responsibility" pattern.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/743783/Reusable-Chain-of-responsibility-in-Csharp

Comment: Ok so here I can say Handler.HandleResponse(response) . What will be the handler and how can i get to know that "text/xml" is one of the handlers? I do not want to use string =="text/xml" .

Comment: Each of the handlers will check if it `CanHandle` the response by doing `return response.ContentType == "text/xml";` there is no real way around that, then  you design the handlers for each content type.